# homebrew update git on mac

Tags: git, homebrew

i'm trying to switch to homebrew's version of git but i get the following message:

```
unknown68a86d401752:~ davidadams$ brew link git
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.4... Warning: Could not link git. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.4/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
Target /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

I don't know enough about Homebrew or bins to know if what this is suggesting is safe to do.

My goal is to start using a current version of git. Terminal tells me the following:

```
unknown68a86d401752:~ davidadams$ which git
/usr/bin/git
unknown68a86d401752:~ davidadams$ git --version
git version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `git-completion.bash` probably didn't change that much anyway, but since you're updating `git` to use the newer version, getting the newer version of that script should be no problem.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: OP asked if it was safe to overwrite that file. The answer is "almost certainly yes."